# How to change path helper names for resource in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a session resource in my routes which is used for authenticating users (login):

```
resource :session,
         only: %i[new create destroy]
```

I want the path helpers to be named login_path (for sessions#new and sessions#create) and logout_path (for sessions#destroy), and actual urls to be '/login', '/logout'

I tried specifying path_names for these actions, but this only changes the actual url, not the helper name.

I have a working solution, but it isn't exactly DRY

```
scope controller: :sessions do
  get 'login', action: :new, as: 'login'
  post 'login', action: :create
  delete 'logout', action: :destroy, as: 'logout'
end
```

Is there a 'pretty' way to do it?

Comment: Are you using devise gem?

Comment: No, logging in is not a big feature of the website (it's just for the administrator to upload text posts). Is it worth to use a separate gem for it?

Comment: In this case use of an `as` modifier is a normal solution.

Comment: Except 'as' doesn't seem to accept a hash. If I do as: 'login', the routes are new_login for 'sessions#new' and login for 'sessions#create' and 'sessions#destroy', which is not really what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

What about it?

`get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
 post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
 post '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'`

Comment: Yes I have a working solution (it's at the bottom of my post), but I wanted one using 'resource'.  I was wondering if that is possible to achieve.